# Normality of the input data and Mahalanobis Taguchi method

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, anomaly-detection

I am using the Mahalanobis-Taguchi method to identify anomaly from a multivariate dataset. The dataset has 30000 data each with 1024 features. Should my data follow a multivariate normal distribution for the method to be effective in detecting anomaly ?